# Internet explorer css issue - my slider is going crazy

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am currently building a website.

And internet explorer is DRIVING me NUTS.

I have 2 sliders on the website, and they go all crazy while browsering in Internet explorer.

Firefox/Chrome is ok - but not Explorer.

Any tips on how to fix this?

The webpage
http://makeitweb.se/

Comment: you might wanna check for CSS inconsistencies.

Comment: What version of IE? Looks fine on IE 9. What do you mean by "crazy"?

Comment: talereader: all the divs just gets stacked all over each other.

Comment: Ok, I managed to reproduce it in IE 9 with IE 7 compatibility mode. I'll have a look for a solution.

Comment: you really need to go through the code on the page.  There are some issues with your markup such as missing `"` on anchor tags and missing closing tags.  Check this out here http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmakeitweb.se%2F

Comment: Henesnarfel : thanks ill check it out aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as far as I can see, the only element that misbehaves in IE 7 is the pager (little blue dots) at the bottom of each slider used to navigate through the slider pages. That's because the dots are `<li>` elements with the style `display: inline-block`, which is not supported by IE 7. It is used to center the `<li>` elements. You need a workaround for this in IE 7.

A quick easy but **dirty** fix would be to add 2 classes definitions in *style.css*, that override the actual classes only for IE 7. You can add this in the page as inline css style, *after* you include the `style.css` file.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
.bx-pager {
    display: block; width: 80px; margin-left: 400px;
}
div.bx-pager li {
    display: inline; float: left;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Why is this dirty? Because if the number of slider boxes will change, you will also have to change the `width: 80px` part and `margin-left: 400px`. There's no automatic centering done, it's a fixed margin.

Now, in order to do it correctly, the alternative is to modify the **bxSlider.js** code to add another `<div>` around the `<li>` elements of the pager, and style that div (`margin: auto`) to get it centered in the existing parent div (that currently gets the class `.bx-pager`).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a million times man - you made my day!

have a great weekend!